Why do maps $E \to E'$ descend to maps between the Thom space $T(E) \to T(E')$?
Let $f: E \to E'$ be a vector bundle homomorphism between $E$ and $E'$, both equipped with metrics. Why does it follow that there exists a map between the Thom spaces $T(E) = D(E) / S(E) \to T(E')$, where $D(E)$ and $S(E)$ are the disk and bundle metrics respectively.
In particular, if $f$ is bundle metric preserving this is clear, but when it isn't how could this possible factor through the quotient? The only thing I can think of is that we can somehow obtain a bundle metric preserving map from $f$ and use that but that doesn't seem correct...

Perhaps there's some background assumption of at least equivalent metrics (those that induce same topology)? For example, all the $p$-norms on $\mathbb{R}^n$ are equivalent.

@SammyBlack All metrics on the same bundle are equivalent (here "metric" means "euclidean metric," i.e. a continuously varying positive definite bilinear form on the fibres). I don't think you can talk about "equivalence of metrics" between two different bundles. What Chris means (I believe) is that $f$ should preserve the norm of its arguments, so that it carries $D(E)$ into $D(E')$ and $S(E)$ into $S(E')$.

Important Edit: As I've learned from this answer, this answer does not work if the bundle maps are not assumed fibrewise linear, and in fact the Thom space construction is not functorial in non-fibrewise linear maps. One should note that for instance the general topology check that $\newcommand{\Th}{\operatorname{Th}}\Th'(f)$ is well-defined hinges on $f$ being proper, and this will only be the case if $f$ is fibrewise injective.

A good approach to figuring out how the functoriality in this definition is supposed to arise is to look at a different construction of the Thom space, one for which the functoriality is clear. How about the following:

Definition: The Thom space $\Th'(E)$ of a vector bundle $E \to B$ over a compact Hausdorff base space $B$ is the one-point compactification
$$
    \Th'(E) = E^+
$$

This version of the Thom space turns out to be homeomorphic to yours when defined; a homeomorphism $\Th(E) \to \Th'(E)$ takes $[S(E)]$, the image of $S(E)$ in the quotient, to $\infty$ and the interior of $D(E)$ to $E \subset E^+$ via the homeomorphism $x \mapsto \frac{x}{1 - \lVert x \rVert}$ (checking that this works out is an exercise in relatively mundane point-set topology, but let me know if you want more details).
For $\Th'(E)$ it's now brilliantly clear what the induced map of $f\colon E \to E'$ should do: When restricted to $E \subset E'$ it should just be itself, i.e. $\Th'(f)(e) = f(e)$ for all $e \in E$, and then you also to send $\infty_E$ somewhere, and what else to do than put $\Th'(f)(\infty_E) = \infty_{E'}$ (one should to check that this is continuous, e.g. by arguing that $f$ is proper).
Now it should be clear what to do for $\Th(E)$, even for non-compact base spaces: Transporting $\Th'(f)$ along the above homeomorphisms, you see that over a compact Hausdorff base $\Th(f)$ is given by taking $f$ to be of the form $f\colon\operatorname{int} D(E) \to \operatorname{int} D(E')$ by composing with the homeomorphisms between the total spaces and the interior of the disk bundles outlined above, letting $\Th(f)(e) = f(e)$ for $e \in \operatorname{int} D(E)$ as before, and sending $[S(E)]$ to $[S(E')]$. This description is then valid also for non-compact bases (again, more point-set topology checks).

It's a bit of a mystery to me why it seems impossible to track down any reference for the functoriality at all; all sources I know assume it either tacitly or outright say that it's clear, but I tend to disagree: As the above shows one needs at least some insight and some point-set legwork to make sure things work out fine.

Thank you this is great. I had the same problem tracking down sources. Would you happen to know when the Thom space of a smooth  vector bundle is also smooth?

@Chris "Smooth" would have to mean "smooth manifold" I assume, and that's essentially never the case: People sometimes say the Thom space is like a "twisted suspension" which refers to the existence of Thom isomorphisms: If $E \to B$ is orientable of rank $n$, then there is an isomorphism $H^(B) \cong \tilde{H}^{ + n}(\operatorname{Th}(E))$ in ordinary cohomology, so your usual tools, in particular things like Poincaré duality will usually rule out the possibility of $\operatorname{Th}(E)$ being a manifold.

That was my thought as well, and perhaps this should be another question, but maybe it is quick enough for a comment. How do people use transversality statements which seem to implicitly assume that $\operatorname{Th}(\gamma_k^r)$ is a smooth manifold? By $\gamma_k^r$ I mean the tautological bundle over the Grassmannian.

@Chris I've not come across an argument like that; what one usually sees (e.g. in arguments around the Pontrayin-Thom construction) is that you take e.g. $\operatorname{Th}(\nu_M)$ where $\nu_M$ is the normal bundle of some submanifold $M \subset \mathbb{R}^n$; this space will generally not be a manifold, but in view of the one-point compactification version of $\operatorname{Th}$ you can still talk about the total space $E(\nu_M)$ as a subspace of $\operatorname{Th}(\nu_M)$ as a smooth manifold, for transversality arguments and such.

If this doesn't cover the argument you have in mind I recommend asking another question :)

that cleared it up thank you.

Wait but what if all of the interior of $D(E)$ is mapped outside of the interior of $D(E')$?

Like I really think it should be $\operatorname{Th}(F)|_{\operatorname{Th}(E)-S(E)}=[F(v)]$ because we don't know whether or not $v$ maps to something that squares to $1$.

@Chris It's irrelevant what $F$ does on $D(E)$: The map $\operatorname{Th}(F)$ is, on the interior of the disk bundle, defined to be $\operatorname{int} D(E) \overset{\cong}{\to} E \overset{F}{\to} E' \overset{\cong}{\to} \operatorname{int} D(E')$ using the homeomorphisms outlined in the answer. In other words, you homeomorphically compress the total spaces $E$ and $E'$ into the interiors of their disk bundles and transport $F$ along these homeomorphisms.

@Chris My answer should give at least a heuristic for why this is the "right thing" to do. There's another version of the Thom space construction which one-point compactifies each fibre separately and then identifies all the points at infinity, which is even closer to your construction: you have $D(E)_x / S(E)_x \cong D^n / S^{n - 1} \cong S^n$ as well as $E_x^+ \cong (\mathbb{R}^n)^+ \cong S^n$ over any point $x$ in the base, so if you want to define $\operatorname{Th}(F)$ fibrewise so that it matches this other definition, you'd better identify the fibre with its open unit disk in some way.

I have been thinking about this a lot, and I think that $\operatorname{Th}(F)|_{\operatorname{Th}(E)-[S(E)]}([v])=[F(v)]$ and then sending $[S(E)]$ and your definition are equivalent, do you disagree?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
